# Why the p99 calculated by grafana exceeds the maximum value of the actual data?

Tags: histogram, prometheus, grafana

I configured a panel in grafana with `controller_runtime_reconcile_time_seconds_bucket`(A Histogram type metric in k8s).
Code looks like this

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, sum (rate(controller_runtime_reconcile_time_seconds_bucket{controller="mljob", mlplatform_cluster_name="$cluster_name"}[$__rate_interval]))by(le))
```

[the panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLG87.png)
There is a lot of points in it that looks close to 1 minute. But the raw data looks much smaller than a minute.

[raw data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66km6.png) [raw data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZYGQ.png) [raw data 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch4bq.png)
The instant data shows that no data falls into the bucket whose upper limit exceeds 1.50 seconds. I know that because grafana will assume that the data is distributed linearly in the bucket, the calculated p99 may be greater than the maximum value of the actual data. But this can't explain the situation I encountered. The calculated p99 is several buckets away from the bucket where the actual maximum value is located.

I even checked the log of the corresponding k8s controller, and I am sure that the time taken by reconsile is much less than 1 minute. I'm very confused about this issue and would be very grateful if someone could point out where the problem might be.

Comment: It was later found that this problem was caused by some missing dots. At those problematic times, there were some le-labeled buckets missing.